# How can I process JSON and modify the request inside Spring Interceptor?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have a REST API using Spring. I've created an Interceptor:

```
@Component
public class CSRFInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        // code here

        return true;
    }
}
```

Every request made is using JSON with the following corresponding Java class:

```
public class CSRFTokenContainer<T> {
    private T data;
    private String csrf;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getCsrf() {
        return csrf;
    }
    public void setCsrf(String csrf) {
        this.csrf = csrf;
    }
}
```

In my Controller it all works well using for example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String create(@RequestBody CSRFTokenContainer<Person> account, HttpServletResponse response) {

        // do something

        return "test";
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to do the following: The Controller should just receive the Person object without the CSRF Token. The CSRF Token should get processed inside the Interceptor. How can I do this? I think the main problem is, that I don't know how to get my CSRFTokenContainer object inside the Interceptor. Afterwards I'd like to modify the request to only contain the "data" part.

Some code example would be nice.

Thank you!

Comment: Please accept some of your previous questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the CSRF problem this way:

I create the token on server side and place it inside the GWT host page via JSP. The token also gets stored in the Session:

myPage.jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="t" uri="myTags" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script>
            <t:csrfToken />
        </script>
        ...
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

myTags.tld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>t</short-name>
    <uri>myTags</uri>

    <tag> 
        <name>csrfToken</name> 
        <tag-class>myapp.server.jsp.CSRFTokenTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>  
</taglib>
```

CSRFTokenTag:

```
public class CSRFTokenTag extends TagSupport {
    private final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    private String generateToken() {
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
        random.nextBytes(bytes);
        return Base64.encode(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        String token = generateToken();

        try {
            pageContext.getOut().write("var " + "myCSRFVarName" + " = \"" + token + "\";");
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        pageContext.getSession().setAttribute("csrfTokenSessionAttributeName", token);

        return SKIP_BODY;
    }

    @Override
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
```

GWT reads the token via JSNI:

```
public class CSRFToken {
    private native static String get()/*-{
        return $wnd["myCSRFVarName"];
    }-*/;
}
```

And with every request the web application sends the token inside a custom HTTP header, for example like this:

```
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "/rest/persons");
rb.setHeader("myCSRFTokenHeader", CSRFToken.get());
rb.setRequestData("someData");
rb.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        // ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        // ...
    }
});
rb.send();
```

Within Spring I've created an Interceptor, that for every request reads the token from the submitted header and checks it:

```
@Component
public class CSRFInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {    
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String sessionCSRFToken = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("csrfTokenSessionAttributeName");

        if(sessionCSRFToken != null && sessionCSRFToken.equals(request.getHeader("myCSRFTokenHeader"))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication required");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's maybe not perfect, but it seems to work pretty well!